# Slide show while using html/css does not work properly

Tags: html, css

i made a slideshow using html and css, but whenever my slideshow auto moves, the scroll stretch instead of moving. you can see my code  here :

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.container,
.section__bg {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.section__bg {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #333333;
}

#header h1,
#header h3 {
  font-size: 33.92px;
  font-family: Myriad Pro;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

#header .header__imgone {
  width: 43px;
  height: 42px;
}

#header .header__in {
  width: 100%;
}

#header .header__container,
#header .header__in {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#header .header__container div,
#header .header__in div {
  margin-left: 6px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #797977;
}

#header .header__container img,
#header .header__in img {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#section {
  color: #fff;
}

#section h2 {
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 18.67px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 40px;
}

#section span {
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 10.67px;
}

#section .section__container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background-color: #333333;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

#section .slideshow {
  background-color: #333333;
  float: left;
  min-width: 391px;
  max-width: 391px;
  border-right: 1px solid #797977;
  margin-top: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}

#section .slideshow__block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

#section .slideshow__block span {
  color: #b1c4d0;
}

#section .slideshow__info {
  padding-right: 16px;
}

#section .slideshow__bottomblock {
  display: flex;
  height: 70px;
  min-height: 70px;
}

#section .slideshow__bottomblock p {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  color: #b1c4d0;
}

#section .slideshow__about {
  flex-direction: column;
}

#section .slideshow__about div {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#section .slideshow__about a {
  border: 1px solid #868684;
  color: #c8c8c8;
  font-size: 10.67px;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  background-color: #868684;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-right: 26px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#section .slideshow__rating {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  margin-left: 13px;
  border-right: 1px dotted #797977;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#section .slideshow__rating span {
  font-family: Myriad Pro;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#section .slideshow__inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#section .slideshow__image img {
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  margin: 0px 13px 0px 13px;
}

#section .slideshow__dots {
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
}

#section .slideshow__dots .slideshow__dot {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 16px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #8a8484;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 0.10em solid #bebeba;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #bebeba;
}

/* Buttons */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border-style: solid;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:decrement {
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-color: #bbbbbb;
  background: url("img/little_arrow.png");
  background-color: #868684;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:increment {
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-color: #bbbbbb;
  background: url("img/little_arrow_right.png");
  background-color: #868684;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slideshow__inner:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}

.slide {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: slide 18s ease-in-out infinite;
  -moz-animation: slide 18s ease-in-out infinite;
  -ms-animation: slide 18s ease-in-out infinite;
  -o-animation: slide 18s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: slide 18s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  25% {
    left: -782px;
  }
  50% {
    left: -1564px;
  }
  75% {
    left: -2346px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -3128px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 360px) {
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
  .slideshow__dots {
    display: flex !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .header__in h1 {
    font-size: 15px !important;
  }
  .header__in h3 {
    font-size: 15px !important;
  }
  .header__in .header__imgtwo {
    width: 50px !important;
    height: 30.5px !important;
  }
  .header__in .header__imgone {
    width: 20px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
  }
  .header__in img {
    margin-left: 7px !important;
    margin-right: 7px !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 782px) {
  .container,
  .section__bg {
    width: 782px;
    min-width: 320px;
  }
}

.clearfix:after,
.container:before,
.container:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}

.clearfix:after,
.container:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tomas Matulionis</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header" id="header">
      <div class="container header__container">
        <div class="header__in">
          <img class="header__imgtwo" src="img/IMDb_icon_.png" alt="IMDb_icon_">
          <h1>Recommends</h1>
          <img class="header__imgone" src="img/Movies-icon.png" alt="Movies-icon">
          <h3>MOVIES</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section" id="section">
      <div class="section__bg">
        <div class="container section__container">
        <div class="slideshow__inner slide">
          <div class="slideshow">
            <div class="slideshow__block">
              <div class="slideshow__image">
                <img src="img/uzduotis_01_792x300.jpg" alt="uzduotis_01_792x300">
              </div>
              <div class="slideshow__about">
                <h2>A Bug's Life</h2>
                <span>Animation, Adventure, Comedy</span>
                <div><a href="#"><img src="img/button_ar.png" alt="arrow"> more</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slideshow__bottomblock">
              <div class="slideshow__rating">
                <img src="img/Layer-11.png" alt="Layer-11">
                <span>8.1</span>
              </div>
              <div class="slideshow__info">
                <p>A misfit ant, looking for "warriors" to save his colony from greedy grasshoppers, recruits a group of bugs that turn out to be an inept circus troupe.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slideshow">
            <div class="slideshow__block">
              <div class="slideshow__image">
                <img src="img/man.jpg" alt="man">
              </div>
              <div class="slideshow__about">
                <h2>All Quiet on <br> the Western Front</h2>
                <span>Drama, War</span>
                <div><a href="#"><img src="img/button_ar.png" alt="arrow"> more</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slideshow__bottomblock">
              <div class="slideshow__rating">
                <img src="img/Layer-11.png" alt="Layer-11">
                <span>8.1</span>
              </div>
              <div class="slideshow__info">
                <p>A young soldier faces profound disillusionment in the soul-destroying horror of World War I.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slideshow">
            <div class="slideshow__block">
              <div class="slideshow__image">
                <img src="img/uzduotis_01_792x300.jpg" alt="uzduotis_01_792x300">
              </div>
              <div class="slideshow__about">
                <h2>A Bug's Life</h2>
                <span>Animation, Adventure, Comedy</span>
                <div><a href="#"><img src="img/button_ar.png" alt="arrow"> more</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slideshow__bottomblock">
              <div class="slideshow__rating">
                <img src="img/Layer-11.png" alt="Layer-11">
                <span>8.1</span>
              </div>
              <div class="slideshow__info">
                <p>A misfit ant, looking for "warriors" to save his colony from greedy grasshoppers, recruits a group of bugs that turn out to be an inept circus troupe.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slideshow">
            <div class="slideshow__block">
              <div class="slideshow__image">
                <img src="img/man.jpg" alt="man">
              </div>
              <div class="slideshow__about">
                <h2>All Quiet on <br> the Western Front</h2>
                <span>Drama, War</span>
                <div><a href="#"><img src="img/button_ar.png" alt="arrow"> more</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slideshow__bottomblock">
              <div class="slideshow__rating">
                <img src="img/Layer-11.png" alt="Layer-11">
                <span>8.1</span>
              </div>
              <div class="slideshow__info">
                <p>A young soldier faces profound disillusionment in the soul-destroying horror of World War I.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slideshow">
            <div class="slideshow__block">
              <div class="slideshow__image">
                <img src="img/uzduotis_01_792x300.jpg" alt="uzduotis_01_792x300">
              </div>
              <div class="slideshow__about">
                <h2>A Bug's Life</h2>
                <span>Animation, Adventure, Comedy</span>
                <div><a href="#"><img src="img/button_ar.png" alt="arrow"> more</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slideshow__bottomblock">
              <div class="slideshow__rating">
                <img src="img/Layer-11.png" alt="Layer-11">
                <span>8.1</span>
              </div>
              <div class="slideshow__info">
                <p>A misfit ant, looking for "warriors" to save his colony from greedy grasshoppers, recruits a group of bugs that turn out to be an inept circus troupe.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slideshow">
            <div class="slideshow__block">
              <div class="slideshow__image">
                <img src="img/man.jpg" alt="man">
              </div>
              <div class="slideshow__about">
                <h2>All Quiet on <br> the Western Front</h2>
                <span>Drama, War</span>
                <div><a href="#"><img src="img/button_ar.png" alt="arrow"> more</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slideshow__bottomblock">
              <div class="slideshow__rating">
                <img src="img/Layer-11.png" alt="Layer-11">
                <span>8.1</span>
              </div>
              <div class="slideshow__info">
                <p>A young soldier faces profound disillusionment in the soul-destroying horror of World War I.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slideshow">
            <div class="slideshow__block">
              <div class="slideshow__image">
                <img src="img/uzduotis_01_792x300.jpg" alt="uzduotis_01_792x300">
              </div>
              <div class="slideshow__about">
                <h2>A Bug's Life</h2>
                <span>Animation, Adventure, Comedy</span>
                <div><a href="#"><img src="img/button_ar.png" alt="arrow"> more</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slideshow__bottomblock">
              <div class="slideshow__rating">
                <img src="img/Layer-11.png" alt="Layer-11">
                <span>8.1</span>
              </div>
              <div class="slideshow__info">
                <p>A misfit ant, looking for "warriors" to save his colony from greedy grasshoppers, recruits a group of bugs that turn out to be an inept circus troupe.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slideshow">
            <div class="slideshow__block">
              <div class="slideshow__image">
                <img src="img/man.jpg" alt="man">
              </div>
              <div class="slideshow__about">
                <h2>All Quiet on <br> the Western Front</h2>
                <span>Drama, War</span>
                <div><a href="#"><img src="img/button_ar.png" alt="arrow"> more</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slideshow__bottomblock">
              <div class="slideshow__rating">
                <img src="img/Layer-11.png" alt="Layer-11">
                <span>8.1</span>
              </div>
              <div class="slideshow__info">
                <p>A young soldier faces profound disillusionment in the soul-destroying horror of World War I.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slideshow">
            <div class="slideshow__block">
              <div class="slideshow__image">
                <img src="img/uzduotis_01_792x300.jpg" alt="uzduotis_01_792x300">
              </div>
              <div class="slideshow__about">
                <h2>A Bug's Life</h2>
                <span>Animation, Adventure, Comedy</span>
                <div><a href="#"><img src="img/button_ar.png" alt="arrow"> more</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slideshow__bottomblock">
              <div class="slideshow__rating">
                <img src="img/Layer-11.png" alt="Layer-11">
                <span>8.1</span>
              </div>
              <div class="slideshow__info">
                <p>A misfit ant, looking for "warriors" to save his colony from greedy grasshoppers, recruits a group of bugs that turn out to be an inept circus troupe.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slideshow">
            <div class="slideshow__block">
              <div class="slideshow__image">
                <img src="img/man.jpg" alt="man">
              </div>
              <div class="slideshow__about">
                <h2>All Quiet on <br> the Western Front</h2>
                <span>Drama, War</span>
                <div><a href="#"><img src="img/button_ar.png" alt="arrow"> more</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slideshow__bottomblock">
              <div class="slideshow__rating">
                <img src="img/Layer-11.png" alt="Layer-11">
                <span>8.1</span>
              </div>
              <div class="slideshow__info">
                <p>A young soldier faces profound disillusionment in the soul-destroying horror of World War I.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow__dots clearfix">
          <div class="slideshow__dot"></div>
          <div class="slideshow__dot"></div>
          <div class="slideshow__dot"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="javascript.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8sgL14c9/).

the scroll bar should move with the slideshow.

Comment: a link to jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/8sgL14c9/

Comment: Can you simplify the code to a small reproducible example? It's easier to answer your question if the pertinent code fits on the screen, and it also makes your question more generally useful.